# how to find unique value from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to find unique value and put that in new array. I have below array:

My code:

```js
var arr = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,5,5,5];
const countUnique = arr => {
   const counts = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      counts[arr[i]] = (counts[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
   };
   return counts;
};
console.log(countUnique(arr));
```

Result: { '1': 4, '2': 4, '3': 3, '5': 3 }

I want to display unique value like Expected Output:
41423335

Hope you understand what I want. but I want to know what's the best way?

Comment: You say you want unique values but you explain trying to get a count of each value. Which one is it? Both of these already have many answers on this site.

Comment: Is your `arr` always sorted? Can it be like `[1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1]`?

Comment: @VLAZ: they want RLEncode it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

Comment: @georg yes `arr` is sorted

Comment: @VLAZ i got your point,

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the `counts` object's entries to a string, and then convert the string to a number using unary `+`:

```js
const countUnique = arr => {
   const counts = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      counts[arr[i]] = (counts[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
   };
   return +Object.entries(counts)
    .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => `${acc}${v}${k}`, '');
};

const arr = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,5,5,5];

console.log(countUnique(arr));
```

Comment: Sharing is caring :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a string with digits and replace with the wanted length and digit.

```js
const
    values = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5],
    result = +values
        .join('')
        .replace(/(.)\1*/g, ({ length }, d) => length + d);

console.log(result);
```